# Is this proof correct, the irrationality of the square root of 2?

Tags: solution-verification, irrational-numbers

I want to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
I suppose that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.
The square of an even number is an even number, same for the odds one.
Then $\sqrt{2}$ can be written like this : $$\sqrt{2} = 2 \cdot k \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Also $\sqrt{2}$ is rational thus can be written like this :
$\sqrt{2} = \frac{1}{b} \cdot a \quad a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^*$

$\frac{1}{b}$ must be equal 2, thus $b =\frac{1}{2}$.
But $b$ is not rational, contradiction.
$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: How do you derive the formula $\sqrt{2} = 2 * k \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: No. Note that $\frac12$ is rational so $b$ is rational.

Comment: If $\sqrt{n}$ is an even integer, then $n$ is even integer. The reverse is not true: If $n$ is an even integer, $\sqrt{n}$ does not have to be an even integer, as it might not be an integer at all.

Comment: Your logic seems to be this: The square of an even integer is an even integer, so the square root of an even integer must also be an even integer. This is false. The correct version is: The square root of an even integer, if it is an integer, must be an even integer. Also, $\frac12$ is rational.

Comment: "$1/b$ must be equal to 2" Why?